# how to display power point file and word file in flutter after getting file path

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

I listed all docx and pptx files from device storage now I want to open them using file path I tried different packages but I am getting a lot of issues can someone provide me a material related to opening document files or any package that can open files using file path thanks

Comment: Welcome! ⚠️️ Software recommendation questions are **off-topic** here for the reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package, it will open the files in default application from its path.

`https://pub.dev/packages/open_file_plus`

https://pub.dev/packages/open_file_plus

Comment: but it open file with suggested app i want to open file in my app

Comment: To open inside the app, use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_filereader

Comment: but inside this package written not supported google play